# NodeJS PDF Generator Data Across Multiple pages

Tags: node.js, pdf, handlebars.js, puppeteer

We have an NodeJS API, that is used to generate PDF's. We use the Handlebars API server side to bind data to HTML templates (i.e. header, footer, content), then we use Puppeteer to generate the PDF's from the bound template.  This approach works great when the data fits on one page.

However, we are trying to determine the best approach when the data spans multiple pages. We are not quite sure how to do this with the current technology.
With the data sorted, the layout is a four column table with the first column having the data sorted down, then once the column is full, it goes to the next column, then the next column, until all columns are full. One all the columns are full go to the next page.

Here is an example of what flow of the data needs to look like this across multiple pages:
https://lucid.app/lucidchart/83cf06f7-7e8a-4eb3-8059-fafd598318a6/view?page=0_0#?folder_id=home&browser=icon

Once the pages have been created they will be sent to the consumer as a single PDF.

Will puppeteer do this paging for us? If so, we have not had much success on how to tell puppeteer to do this. Do we have to create PDF's for each page and somehow stitch them together in a single document?
We are open to ideas on how to do this with the current technology (NodeJS, puppeteer, handlebars) or using a different NodeJS technology. The only requirement is it has to be server side and run in NodeJS.

Again we are open to any ideas on how to do this?
Examples are encouraged.